# reactnative package.json dependencies updation

Tags: react-native, github, npm, dependencies

I am creating a react-native application. Here I am creating one library on npm as well. And using this library from my react application inside package.json.

Now, I want to automate one task here. If I update the code and version of my library on npm, my react-native application should adopt the new version automatically.

How could I achieve this task?

Any ideas regarding same?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

If your library is on any remote server and you have added it into your project using package manager (like yarn).
Now you have updated your library but it will not update automatically in your react native project.

You have to achieve this manually by specifying the library version.

yarn add package-name@1.2.3

Refer: [package using yarn](https://yarnpkg.com/lang/en/docs/cli/add/)